# Cobalt segmentation fault in blitter

Tags: cobalt

From today, the Cobalt application that uses blitter/directFB layer does crash while starting with the below segmentation fault.

It seems to be linked with animated images but even by disabling it with --disable_image_animations the crash still occurs.

The same issue occurs with qual-e.appspot.com/webp.html and qual-e.appspot.com/awebp.html

Do you know how to solve the issue? In the meantime is it possible to disable animated images?

> Caught signal: SIGSEGV (11)
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f62de]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f7b88]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f66f0]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f7b88]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f7b88]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f7b88]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f66f0]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f7b88]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::RenderTreeNodeVisitor::Visit()
>   [0x12f5e74]
>     cobalt::renderer::rasterizer::blitter::HardwareRasterizer::Impl::Submit()
>   [0x12f4d58]
>     cobalt::renderer::Pipeline::RasterizeSubmissionToRenderTarget()
>   [0x1096350]   cobalt::renderer::Pipeline::RasterizeCurrentTree()
>   [0x1097630]   base::Timer::RunScheduledTask() [0x4a5cf8]
>     MessageLoop::RunTask() [0x479d24]
>     MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask() [0x47aacc]
>     MessageLoop::DoDelayedWork() [0x47b83c]
>     base::MessagePumpDefault::Run() [0x47f188]  base::RunLoop::Run()
>   [0x48ae80]    MessageLoop::Run() [0x4794cc]   base::Thread::ThreadMain()
>   [0x4a44ec]    base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x4a38b8]
>     (anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc() [0x4bb670]  start_thread
>   [0x77f73e14] Aborted

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with WebP support.
Please file a bug here w/ your Cobalt version, build type, Starboard, stracktrace information.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120&template=699202